# Do primitive variables inherently have pointers to them in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I know we don't initialize pointers to primitive variables when we initialize primitive variables, but is it being done under the hood? I received some comments like that on a reddit post, and I just wanted to clear up some of my confusion. If my question doesn't make sense, please let me know so I can reword my question.Thanks!

Comment: Every named variable has an address (in the abstract machine), if that's what you mean

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. For starters, what do you mean by "primitive variables"? Then there's this premise: "I know we don't initialize pointers to primitive variables when we initialize primitive variables" What you know seems wrong? `char *p = NULL;` initializes a pointer when initializing a variable. But again, it depends on your meaning of "primitive variable".

Comment: `is it being done under the hood` are you asking whether pointers are automatically initialized to 0? are you asking how every non-macro object in C has its own address(eg who decides what that address is)? are you asking whether pointers are just numbers referring to indices in the virtual memory? It's difficult to tell what you are asking.

Comment: Are you asking about, for example, `int i = 0`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing "primitive variables" refers to the built in, non-pointer data types like `int`, `float`, `double`, `char`, and `void`. You're asking if `int i = 42` has a pointer "under the hood".

Let's look "under the hood". Consider this simple program:

```
int main() {
  int i = 42;
  printf("%d", i);
}
```

"Under the hood" means looking at the compiled assembly, basically the human readable machine code. You can see this by compiling with -S. The relevant part is...

```
# Allocate 64 bits on this function's stack.
pushq %rbp

...

leaq L.str(%rip), %rdi
movl $42, %esi
xorl %eax, %eax
callq _printf
xorl %eax, %eax

L.str:
  .asciz "%d"
```

Without going into a bunch of assembly, what that means is the value `42` is stored in the executable file. `42` is copied to a [CPU register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) (memory inside the CPU). `printf` reads from that register.

The value `42` is copied from the executable file directly to the CPU. Nothing like a pointer is made.

The details will vary from compiler to compiler, optimization flags, the C code being compiled, and so on.